# Strange behaviour between tag-helpers and Route attribute in asp.net 5 MVC6

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net5

When I use asp-controller and asp-action in a `<a>` tag for another Action than the current, in a View called by a Controller Method with a `[Route]` attribute, the generated link have an empty `href` attribute.

**In the Controller:**

```
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    [Route("[action]/{sectionId:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowSection(int sectionId)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

**In the View:**

```
<a asp-controller="Forum" asp-action="Index">Index</a>
<a asp-controller="Forum" asp-action="ShowSection" asp-route-sectionId="@Model.ParentSection.Id">@Model.ParentSection.Name</a>
```

**Generated html:**

```
<a href="">Index</a>
<a href="/ShowSection/1">Général</a>
```

As you can see, the first link is not generated correctly. All of the links that target another Action than the currenct Action are generated with an empty `href` tag.

**When I remove the [Route] attribute of the ShowSection action:**

```
<a href="/Forum">Index</a>
<a href="/Forum/ShowSection?sectionId=1">Général</a>
```

As you can see, the links are correctly generated.

How can I fix this while keeping my `[Route]` attributes (or with an alternative)?

Comment: Show your `Index()` action along with the routing registration in your `Startup.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it (@haim770 comment helped) :

I added a Route attribute to all my controllers & actions and now it works.